# Google Calendar Inserting Event results in "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, google-calendar-api

My code:

I have this in my code-behind file.

```
Event newEvent = new Event
            {
                Summary = "Tin Roof",
                Description = "Its gonna be epic",
                Location = "Claremont",
                Start = new EventDateTime
                {
                    Date = "2012-02-14", 
                    DateTime = "2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00",
                    TimeZone = "Cape Town",                    
                },
            };

            _service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "validcalendarId@group.calendar.google.com").Fetch();
```

This the error i get over the line where i try to insert the event into a calendar.
The Error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Required [400]
Errors [
    Message[Required] Location[ - ] Reason[required] Domain[global]
]
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm getting the same error using the url  https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/name@gmail.com/events?alt=json&prettyPrint=true

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the URL. If the URL looks ok on the client side, I recommend looking at access logs on your server to see what URL is being hit. 4xx errors mean a resource was not found. If the endpoint was correct, but the request was fubared, you would get a 5xx error code. (Assuming that your server side frameworks uses standard HTTP Response Codes).

Answer (score 0):

i know its an old post, but the timezone doesn't look correct.  try using Africa/Johannesburg instead.  also if you use a date field it does an 'all day' calendar entry.  otherwise use a start time.  You should also add an end time object.